# clickable icons within a sortable tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been working on a sortable tree list for our customers to organize their website. you can add and drag pages. Each li contains the name of the page and 3 icons( lock, visable and edit)

The thing I can't figure out is to get these icons clickable. When you click one of the icons you just start dragging that li instead.

For the nestable list I am using dbushell's nestable : https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

This is an example of my nestable list:

```
 <div class="dd">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 1<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 2<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 3<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 4<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="5">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 5<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

like described in dbushell's nestable guide I used `$('.dd').nestable();` to make this tree sortable/nestable.

this is click function I can't get to work :

```
$(".icon").click(function() {
 console.log("click");
    });
```

I hope that I provided enough information, If not let me know. Also i am just a beginner in programming and new on stackoverflow. If there is anything else I did wrong I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) ... Try :

```
 $(".lock").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("click");
 });
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mym6u69/) ... Check what happens if you remove the `stopPropagation`

Answer (score 0):

After puzzling around in devtools in chrome I found that I had to put the icon outside of the handle.

```
<div class="dd">
    <ol class="dd-list">                      put the icon  here
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">  <----
              <div class="dd-handle">Item 1<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 2<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 3<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 4<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="5">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 5<img class="icon" src="iconpath" style="float:right;"></div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I did also have to use Danko's answer.